Mass Update of SSH Keys
I recently upgraded our Master Server from Oracle Linux 8.8 to Oracle Linux 9.3.
Unfortunately, on a lot of our systems we still use RSA keys for ssh authentication, and they are not working anymore with OpenSSH 8.7.
So I need to roll out new ECDSA keys.
As I have to do this for about 150+ servers, I was trying to simplify the process with a for loop like this:
for a in $(grep -v "^#" /etc/hosts | grep -i "fs"  | awk '{print $2}'); do ssh-keygen -R $a; sshpass -p 'PASSWORDXYZ' ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i id_ecdsa $a; done

When I try to log in to any of the changed servers, I get this prompt:
$ ssh acefs150
The authenticity of host 'server1 (X.X.X.X)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:XYZHDKLLDJ.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:293: server2
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:296: server3
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:297: server4
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:305: server24
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:306: server26
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:307: server180
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:310: server185
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:312: server88
    (105 additional names omitted)
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes

This seems kind of strange to me, as every server should have its own host key, shouldn't it?
After entering "yes" once, I never got asked again.
Am I doing the whole process in the correct way, or is there a better way to do this?

Possibly the ServerFault SE may be more relevant (links on top right icon) because you asked for "proper way" (at such scale). IIRC there is also a method to roll out new keys, but I'm not doing things at such scale, so I never cared.

"every server should have its own host key , shouldnt it?" - yes, unless you have cloned the machines and not regenerated the host keys. "is there a better way to do this?" - if you have a configuration management system, use that, otherwise no.

I don't understand the problem. RSA keys did not stop working with OpenSSH 8.7 – they still work in the very latest release.

For whatever reason they did not work anymore. Also regarding to documentation rsa was disabled in this release


as every server should have its own host key, shouldn't it?

It should but if someone is using a golden image to implement the hosts or simply cloning an existing host an NOT regenerating the host key, this happens.
Fixing this is going to create a lot more problems as any client which has seen the current key is going to complain if you replace it.
mkdir /etc/ssh/oldkeys
mv /etc/ssh/*key /etc/ssh/oldkeys
mv /etc/ssh/*.pub /etc/ssh/oldkeys
ssh-keygen -A


In fact all of the servers are installed using a preconfigured VM image.
So just for clarification: The SSH Keys need to be renewed on all of the 150 servers with those commands?

"need to" is a question of policy. I would be doing it if it were my decision.

I don't think the message is strictly related to issued command.
Probably remote hosts already had the same (old) keys, that you accepted once, yesterday or 10 years ago.
When you removed those, new (but cloned) ED25519 identities popped up.
